# extract multiple xml nodes into array without looping

Tags: xml, excel, xmldom, vba

I have a xml doc that looks like this:

```
<rng>
  <col1>
    <row1>A</row1>
    <row2>B</row2>
    <row3>C</row3>
    <row4>D</row4>
  </col1>
  <col2>
    <row1>E</row1>
    <row2>F</row2>
    <row3>G</row3>
    <row4>H</row4>
  </col2>
</rng>
```

There are a *lot* more of the col nodes, and each one contains several thousand row elements.

I'd like to parse out the values from the row elements and ultimately put them onto a spreadsheet. I'm currently doing this as follows:

```
' get a list of the col elements (thi sits in a loop to go through them all)
Set oXMLColNodeList = oXMLDoc.selectNodes("//saveStates/rng/*")

' Lop through each column
For colNum = 1 To oXMLColNodeList.Length
    ' get all the row nodes for that coulmn
    Set oXMLRowNodeList = oXMLDoc.selectNodes("//saveStates/rng"/col" & colNum & "/*")

    ' loop through all the row nodes
    For rowNum = 1 To oXMLRowNodeList.Length
       ' get the node to do something with it 
       Set oXMLNode = oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//saveStates/rng/col" & colNum & "/row" & rowNum)


    next rowNum
next colNum
```

I.e. I'm looping through the col nodes, then through each of the row nodes to get the values A, B, C, D etc. It's catastrophically slow when the number of row elements goes towards the tens of thousands.

I don't have much experience with parsing from XML docs, I'm looking for a way to extract all the values from the 'row*' nodes at the same time, without having to loop through them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the **ADO DB Recordset** to open the xml DOM Document in a Recordset, then use **Range.CopyFromRecordset** method to dump the data into Excel after adding a filter to only get the records you want?

here is some sample code from [MSDN: How to obtain a Recordset from XML](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263247)

```
Public Function RecordsetFromXMLDocument(XMLDOMDocument As DOMDocument) As Recordset
Dim oRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
dim destRange as range

set destrange=range("B2")

Set oRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

oRecordset.Open XMLDOMDocument 'pass the DOM Document instance as the Source argument

Set RecordsetFromXMLDocument = oRecordset  'return the recordset

destRange.CopyFromRecordset oRecordset 

Set oRecordset = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - it's a good idea, but can't be used to load the random looking xml that I'm using. It has to already have been saved as xml via a recordset. I might come back to it, but at the minute I don't want to mess with the xml layout

Comment: Maybe you could try this: [XML in Excel](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/XMLAndExcel05.asp)

Answer (score 0):

@chrisSpaceman, 
here you find a shorter way using XMLDOM. I added some declarations in order to show a complete example (I assume you know how to manipulate arrays, so I left that beside).

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReadRows()

'Declarations
Dim oXMLDoc         As Object    ' XML document (object)
'Dim oXMLColNodeList As Object   ' you don't need this list any more ! 
Dim oXMLRowNodeList As Object    ' needed node list
Dim oXMLNode        As Object    ' single node within this list
Dim xPE             As Object    ' ParseError object
Dim strErrText      As String    ' Error message
Dim sFileName       As String    ' user defined file path
' =================================
' 0. User defined File Name <==  !
' =================================
  sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data\test.xml"
' =================================
' 1. XML Declaration oXMLDoc
' =================================
' Set oXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60                   ' Early Binding
  Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")     ' Late  Binding

' XPath, Validation
  oXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXMLDoc.validateOnParse = False
' =================================
' 2. Load XML File
' =================================
  If oXMLDoc.Load(sFileName) Then
     MsgBox sFileName & " successfully loaded"
  Else
  ' Set ParseError Object
    Set xPE = oXMLDoc.parseError

    With xPE
      strErrText = "Load Error " & .ErrorCode & " XML File " & vbCrLf & _
        Replace(.URL, "file:///", "") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        xPE.reason & _
        "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Line No:    " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
        "Line Pos:  " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
        "File Pos:  " & .filepos & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End With
    MsgBox strErrText, vbExclamation
    Set xPE = Nothing
    Set oXMLDoc = Nothing
   'Stop procedure
    Exit Sub
  End If
' =================================
' 3 Set only one Nodelist
' =================================
  Set oXMLRowNodeList = oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("rng/*/*")

' =================================
' 4. loop through all (row) nodes
' =================================
  For Each oXMLNode In oXMLRowNodeList
     Debug.Print oXMLNode.Text
   ' read in ...
  Next oXMLNode

 ' 5. terminate oXMLDoc
  Set oXMLDoc = Nothing
 End Sub
```

**Remarks** This code avoids too much loops by setting only one NodeList to your col tags via wild card (as the col and row nodes don't have siblings). Furthermore I would refer to `DocumentElement` instead of using //saveStates, if this actually represents your root node.